# UITableView Back Button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two UItableViews and the problem i am having is in going back from the second UITableView to the first UITableView. I have applied the back button using:

```
- (IBAction)BackButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The issue is that it takes me back to the previous UITableView but when I click on the row of that UITableView it returns an empty UITableView where there should be data in it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int i = 0;
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i = (indexPath.row * 4);
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [ParsedData objectAtIndex:i]);      
    SubList *SubListNib = [[SubList alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubList" bundle:nil];
    self->newSubList = SubListNib;
    newSubList.folderid = [ParsedData objectAtIndex:i];
    [self presentModalViewController:SubListNib animated:YES];
}
```

[image]
The Data gets entered in the Array the first time.

[image]
On going to the previous screen and coming back the data does not enter the array.

Comment: show ur viewwillappear code.

Comment: So you are displaying a modal view from a modal view?

Comment: did you assign delegate to  tableview ??

Comment: @Hinata Hyuga: I am new to iOS so will u please explain the viewwillappearcode

Comment: array from which you are showing data in table, add that in viewdidload function, and then reload your first table in viewwillappear function.

Comment: I did that but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You should reload first tableview, when you returns from second tableview to first by

[firstTableViewName reloadData];

This method must also be include in backbutton click.

Comment: How can i reload data of my first uitableview in the back button click of the second table view?